# can't find ros message API ducouments

Tags: ros, rosmessage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I currently can't find any API documents about ros messages like std_msgs, mavros_msgs...ect, including all member functions, class definitions or structures. It  suppose be there, but I can't google it anymore.
Is that because server problem or it will not be access any more.
Thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234452/can%27t-find-ros-message-api-ducouments/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2016-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-05-16**:
I'm not having any trouble with the documentation at http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs .Presumably you have a link to documentation that doesn't exist any more; perhaps if you provide a link to that documentation we can help figure out where it went.

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2016-05-17**:
Hi @ahendrix, what I mean is not the link you provided. The documentation here:https://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/std_msgs/html/namespacestd__msgs.html, I can jut find in mirror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short, you should not be referring to that documentation. It's generated based on the generated headers, and discards the message semantics.

The other reason why you can't find any documentation about member functions on the message types is because there are no public member functions; generated C++ types are only classes with public data members, also known as POD types (plain old data).

Instead, you should be referring to the [msg API](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/std_msgs/html/index-msg.html) link on the [std_msgs wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs), or the documentation on the page itself. You can infer the generated C++ type name and [field types](http://wiki.ros.org/msg) directly from the message generation.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0